# Prov that function is eventually periodic to origin.

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence, dynamical-systems

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^4$ by

$f(w,x,y,z) = (\mid w-x \mid,\mid x-y \mid,\mid y-z \mid,\mid z-w \mid)$

1. Prove that for any $(w,x,y,z) \in \mathbb{Z}^4$ there is $n>0$ such that $f^n(w,x,y,z)=(0,0,0,0)$
2. Prove that there is no $n$ such that $f^n(w,x,y,z)=(0,0,0,0)$ for all $(w,x,y,z) \in \mathbb{Z}^4$

---

I wrote a computer code in R that can execute this function for any integers $w,x,y,z$ and $n$. See below:

```
rm(list = ls())  
myfun=function(w,x,y,z){  
outcome <- c(abs(w-x), abs(x-y), abs(y-z),abs(z-w))  
return(outcome)  
}  
w<-1  
x<-3  
y<-534  
z<-3  
n=6  

outcome <- matrix (nrow=n, ncol=4)  
for (i in 1:n){  
outcome[i,] <- myfun(w,x,y,z)  
w <- outcome[i,1]  
x <- outcome[i,2]  
y <- outcome[i,3]  
z <- outcome[i,4]  
}  
outcome
```

---

After executing 100's of points I see that after, $n=5$ we see the function going to $(0,0,0,0)$. I tried using brute force and applied the function 6 times by hand to see if it cancels out but I've end up with a very complex function. There must be a cleaner way of proving this question. Point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Hint(s). You can assume all the arguments are positive (why)? What happens to the sizes of the arguments after the next iteration?

Comment: It won't always just take 5 iterations! (If it did, then $n=5$ would have $f^n(x,y,z,w)=(0,0,0,0)$ for all $(x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb{Z}^4$.)

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith I meant after 5 iterations. The 6th iteration will always be (0,0,0,0)

Comment: @EthanBolker The arguments are positive due to the absolute value in the function. I don't see a pattern in terms of the sizes of arguments.

Comment: Can you show that the arguments get smaller (in some appropriate sense) each time?

Comment: @EthanBolker Absolutely! Using the reverse triangle inequality

Comment: @EthanBolker For any point, if I let n=6 then that function will go to (0,0,0,0) (According to my computer program). This makes sense due to the reverse inequality, the function arguments are decreasing in size. 

How can I use these facts to prove the statements?

Comment: The decrease should show you how to prove (1). If (2) is true (you've been asked to prove it) then 6 iterations can't always work - your program doesn't test enough cases. Since (presumably) (2) is true, your program will not help no matter how far you go. But the intermediate results may show you how to construct a starting point that will take a long time to get to all zero (I don't know but that's where I'd start).

Comment: @Winther - The max element never grows (other then the first time when the arguments can be negative) and can be shown to decrease after at most 4 applications.

Comment: For the first part: Can we apply contraction mapping to show it is eventually a fixed point?

Comment: @Nadia - I agree with Ethan Bolker. It can't actually always be zero after 6 iterations.

Comment: By random search, one can find starting arbitrarily long iteration sequences. Say, for $10,536,452,296$ there are 15 iterations.

Comment: Yes as @EthanBolker pointed out, by part 2 of the question there is no fixed number of iterations where the the function goes to $(0,0,0,0)$ for all points.

Comment: @zhoraster that is the first point I have come across where it takes more than 5 iterations. Surprising

Comment: (0,1,2,4) needs 7 steps

Answer (score 5):

**1**. Let us show that $f^n(v)\to 0$, $n\to\infty$, for any $v=(a,b,c,d)\in \mathbb{R}^4$. It is enough to consider non-negative vectors. It is clear that $f$ does not increase the maximum of the numbers, which we denote by $||v||$. Therefore, there exists the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} ||f^n(v)||$. In particular, the sequence $\{f^n(v),n\ge 1\}$ has a limit point, say, $v_0$.

Clearly, $||f^m(v_0)|| = ||v_0||$ for any $m\ge 0$. Also, extracting a convergent subsequence for preimages of elements converging to $v_0$, $v_0 = f(u_0)$.

Assume that $v_0\neq 0$. Let $a>0$ be the maximal coordinate of $f(v_0)$, wlog the first. Then $v_0$ has either the form $(a,0,*,*)$ or $(0,a,*,*)$. Moreover, the sum of the remaining coordinates must be $a$ due to the fact that $v_0 = f(u_0)$.

*Case a* Both remaining coordinates are less that $a$ (and therefore positive). Then we have either (here $c$ means any number less then $a$) $$(a,0,c,c)\to (a,c,c,c) \to (c,c,c,c),$$
or
$$(0,a,c,c)\to (a,c,c,c) \to (c,c,c,c),$$
which contradicts to $||f^m(v_0)|| = ||v_0||$.

*Case b* One of the remaining coordinates is $a$ (and the other is zero). Then we have essentially two possibilities
$$
(a,0,a,0)\to (a,a,a,a)\to (0,0,0,0),
$$
and 
$$
(0,a,a,0)\to (a,0,a,0)\to (a,a,a,a)\to (0,0,0,0),
$$
both contradicting the assumption.

Therefore, $v_0=0$, hence, $\lim_{n\to\infty} f^n(v) = 0$, as claimed.

**2**. First we prove this for real numbers. [**Notice**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x-1)(x%2B1)%5E3+%2B1+%3D+0) that the polynomial $(x-1)(x+1)^3+1$ has a positive root $\lambda \approx 0.83929$. Set $(t,u,v,w) = (1,1+\lambda,(1+\lambda)^2,(1+\lambda)^3)$. Then $$f(t,u,v,w) = (\lambda,\lambda(1+\lambda),\lambda(1+\lambda)^2,(1+\lambda)^3-1)\\
 = (\lambda,\lambda(1+\lambda),\lambda(1+\lambda)^2,\lambda(1+\lambda)^3)=\lambda\cdot (t,u,v,w).$$ (I'll not write the vector here, since $\lambda$ is a cumbersome root of a cubic equation, and $(t,u,v,w)$ is even more cumbersome; the numerical values are $(t,u,v,w)\approx (1, 1.8393, 3.383, 6.2223)$.) Therefore,  for any $n\ge 1$  $f^n(t,u,v,w) = \lambda^n\cdot (t,u,v,w)\neq 0$.

Now by way of contradiction assume that there exists $n\ge 1$ such that $f^n(a,b,c,d) = 0$ for any integer $a,b,c,d$. Then, obviously, $f^n(a,b,c,d) = 0$ for any rational $a,b,c,d$. In view of continuity, $f^n(a,b,c,d) = 0$ for any real $a,b,c,d$, which contradicts the previous paragraph.

---

This proof also gives a way to construct integer quadruples leading to arbitrarily long iteration sequences: one just needs to multiply $(t,u,v,w)$ by a large number and take integer parts. Say, the approximate values $(10000,18393,33830,62223)$ lead to a $24$-step iteration sequence.

---

The application of this method for triples (perhaps, unsurprisingly) leads to funny example of long iteration triples: $(F_{n-2},F_{n-1},F_n)$, where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number.

Comment: I added "f" after the word matrix. as you didn't name it  explicitly. Fine proof.

Comment: So the function f is defined by means of A.  Somebody  who hasn't read the comments might ask you state a def'n of f ,  but I have no problem understanding your solution.

Comment: Sorry about that............

Comment: @user254665, I've removed the matrix $A$, as it is not very relevant.

Comment: The first part of the question is false if you take $\Bbb Z^3$  instead of $\Bbb Z^4$, since  $(n,n,0)$ yields a periodic sequence for every $n$. How you rule out periodic sequences in the case $\Bbb Z^4$?

Comment: @san, considering some zillion cases probably. Quite boring, but can't think of another technique at the moment. A better question is why (or whether) $f^n(a,b,c,d)\to 0$ for *real* $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: I liked it better with the matrix. It made it easy to see how you got the polynomial, and, for me, easy to grasp the proof as a whole. However, it's your proof. +1.

Comment: @user254665, maybe the order of sentences is not optimal now, but the idea is more natural. You start by looking for a vector $z = (1,u,v,w)$ with $1<u<v<w$ such that $f(z) = \lambda z$. Then you must have $u=1+\lambda$, $v=(1+\lambda)^2$, $w = (1+\lambda)^3$. Hence, using that $f(z) = \lambda z$, you get $\lambda (1+\lambda)^3 = (1+\lambda)^3-1$.

Comment: @san, it is hard to read the comments. You can post an alternative answer, this will be more convenient.

Comment: @zhoraster, I have a few questions.
First part:
i) You start your proof by showing $f^n(v)\to 0$, $n\to\infty$, for any $v=(a,b,c,d)\in \mathbb{R}^4$. Why cant we just start in similar faishon but for  $v=(a,b,c,d)\in \mathbb{Z}^4$    
  
ii) Why is it important to show that the sum of the remaining coordinates must be $a$?

Comment: i) yes, we can; the proof is considerably simpler. I just found the integer case not funny enough.   ii) if we don't use this, then there are just some few more cases to consider (not so much though).

Comment: @zhoraster For the second part: In the contradiction part of the proof, we show how $f^n(a,b,c,d)=(0,0,0,0) for integers and similar for rationals. You then proceed to "in the view of continuity,.." and showed the function is zero for all reals (thus contradiction). Why in the view of continuity, the function of reals is zero?

Comment: @Nadia, because each real $x$ is a limit of rational $q_k$. Then $f^n(x) = \lim f^n(q_k) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$\bf{First\ part}$. We prove the statement given by Paul Sinclair in a comment:

The max element never grows (other then the first time when the arguments can be negative) and it decreases after at most 4 applications, if you start at a non-zero quadruple.

1. We assume that $f:\Bbb{N}_0^4\to \Bbb{N}_0^4$.
2. Then clearly $Max(f(V))\le Max(V)$ for all $V$.
3. If $Max(f(V))= Max(V)$, for some $V\ne 0$, then one of the entries of $V$ is $0$ and it is adjacent to the maximal value $m$ (note that we consider the first entry adjacent to the fourth, due to invariance under rotation).
4. Consequently, if all values of $V$ are different to its adjacent values, then none of the entries of $f(V)$ is zero, hence
   $Max(f(f(V)))< Max(f(V))\le Max(V)$.

Now start with a $0\ne V\in \Bbb{N}_0^4$, and we have to prove that $Max(f^k(V))<Max(V)$ for some $k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.

If $Max(f(V))<Max(V)$, there is nothing to prove.

Else we can assume by 3. that $V=(m,0,a,b)$ with $0\le a,b\le m$.

If $0\ne a$, $a\ne b$ and $b\ne m$, then by 4. we have $Max(f(f(V)))<Max(V)$ 
and we are done.

Hence we have to consider the three cases
$$
V=(m,0,0,b),\quad V=(m,0,a,a)\quad\text{and}\quad V=(m,0,a,m).
$$
In the first case, if $b=0$, then $f^4(V)=(0,0,0,0)$; if $b=m$ or $b=m/2$, then 
$f^3(V)=(0,0,0,0)$ and if $b\ne 0,m/2,m$, then all elements of 
$f(V)$ are different, hence by 4. we have $Max(f(f(f(V))))<Max(V)$.

In the second case, if $a=m$ or $a=0$, then $f^4(V)=(0,0,0,0)$, and 
else all entries of $f(V)$ are different from the adjacent entries, 
hence by 4. we have  $Max(f(f(f(V))))<Max(V)$.

In the third case, if $a=0$, then $f^3(V)=(0,0,0,0)$; if $a=m$ or 
$a=m/2$, then $f^4(V)=(0,0,0,0)$ and if $a\ne 0,m/2,m$, then all elements of 
$f(V)$ are different, hence, by 4., $Max(f(f(f(V))))<Max(V)$.

This proves the assertion. Note that for $V=(m,0,0,0)$ we have $Max(f^3(V))=m=Max(V)$.
Hence, if you start with any quadruple in $\Bbb{N}_0^4$ with $Max(V)=m$, after at most $4m$ steps it goes to zero, i.e., $f^{4m}(V)=(0,0,0,0)$.

${\bf{Conclusion\ of\ the\ first\ part:}}$ If you start with $(x,y,z,t)\in \Bbb Z^4$, then $V=f((x,y,z,t))\in \Bbb N_0^4$, hence $f^n(x,y,z,t)=0$ for $n=4 Max(V)+1$.

$\bf{Second\ part}$. 
If a quadruple $V=(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ satisfies $v_1\le v_3$ and $\Delta:=v_4−(v_1+v_2+v_3)\ge 0$,
then the cuadruple $C:=(0,2v_1+\Delta,2v_4−2v_3,2v_4+\Delta)$ satisfies $f(f(C))=2f(V)$, and also 
$c_1\le c_3$ and $c_4−(c_1+c_2+c_3)\ge 0$.

If $\Delta$ is even, then we can take $\overline C:=\frac 12 (0,2v_1+\Delta,2v_4−2v_3,2v_4+\Delta)$, and then 
$f(f(\overline C))=f(V)$.

Starting from any $V=(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ satisfying $v_1\le v_3$ and $\Delta:=v_4−(v_1+v_2+v_3)\ge 0$,
such that $V$ needs $n$ steps to go to zero ($f^n(V)=(0,0,0,0)$ and $f^{n-1}(V)\ne (0,0,0,0)$), 
we can construct (iterating the construction above) an infinite family $V_k$ with $V_0=V$ and $V_1=C$ (or $V_1=\overline C$), 
such that $V_k$ needs $n+k$ steps to go to zero.
This proves the second part.

For example, we can consider $V_0=V=(0,0,1,2)$, which needs four steps to go to zero. 
Then $V_3=(0,1,3,7)$ needs seven steps to go to zero.

If we set $V=V_0=(0,0,0,1)$, then $V_3=(0,1,2,4)$ needs 7 steps and $V_{11}=(0,20,57,125)$ needs 15 steps.

${\bf{Edit:}}$ Via OEIS on the last entry of the last example ($V_0=(0,0,0,1)$) I found that the problem is solved completely in
http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/AMM-May05_Boxes.pdf

There they found $(0,1,q^2-q,q)$ as a fixpoint of the operation on certain equivalence classes, with $q^3-q^2-q-1=0$, which is related to the $\lambda$ in the answer of zhoraster via $q=\lambda+1$.

Comment: This is a good construction. In fact, it nearly coincides with another one I was going to give. We know that a polynomial corresponds to a recurrent equation; in our case $1+\lambda$ is a root of $x^3-x^2-x-1=0$, which corresponds to the recurrence $t_{n+3} = t_{n+2} + t_{n+1} + t_n$. So we end up with a tribonacci sequence of long-iteration examples. There are several tribonacci sequences: starting with $0,0,1$; $0,1,1$; $1,1,1$. Starting from $0,0,1$ with your approach will give all three of them (I look at $f(V)$ from your construction rather than $V$ itself) at different steps modulo 3.

Comment: Naturally, all the constructed examples will then be close to $(n,n(1+\lambda), n(1+\lambda)^2, n(1+\lambda)^3)$. For example, starting from $0,0,1$ as in above comment, after $20$ steps we arrive to $(927,1705,3136,5768)$, which is $(927, [927(1+\lambda)], [927(1+\lambda)^2], [927(1+\lambda)^3])$, where $[]$ denotes the integer part.

Comment: Very nice proof. Just one question for the first part. When we're examining the rest of the cases, why are we looking at the case $b=m/2$ and $b \neq m/2$ ? Isn't it enough to see if it holds for just $b=m$ and $b \neq m$ ?

Comment: @san In the second case if $a=m$ or $a=0$ then it should be $f^4(V)=(0,0,0,0)$,

Comment: @san The first part proves the assertion, not the first part of the question.

Comment: Error corrected and conclusion of the proof of the first part added.

Comment: If $b=m/2$ in the first case, then $f(V)=(m,0,m/2,m/2)$, so it doesn't hold that all entries are different.

Comment: @san you deleted your comment where you defined V before you wrote this proof. Can you add the comment to the proof? (ie define V)

Comment: I don't remember which $V$ you mean.

Comment: @san The first part. I think you meant "if you start with a non-zero quadruple $V$". Once we prove the assertion, how can we then go and prove the first part of the question?

Comment: @san First part, point 3. 

If $V=(m,a,b,0)$ then $Max(V)=Max(f(V))$ . However 0 is not adjacent to m?

Comment: @san Are you sure about the conclusion. Maybe my interpertation is wrong but I'm reading this as:

if we choose $(10,2,1,3)$ then $V=f((10,2,1,3))=(8,1,2,7)$ and so it takes $n=4Max(V)+1$ steps for $f$ to go $(0,0,0,0)$ which means it takes $n=4*8+1=33$ steps for $f$ to go $(0,0,0,0)$

Comment: The quadruples are equivalent under rotation and reflexion,so $(m,a,b,0)$ is equivalent to $(0,m,a,b)$, which is equivalent to $(b,a,m,0)$ and to $(m,0,b,a)$. All this is explained in the article mentioned above.

Comment: In the article a better bound is given, what I say is that in this particular case it takes less than 33 steps to go to zero.